# Is this a proof of the Newton-Leibniz formula

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Lets say we prove the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$F(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt \Rightarrow F'(x) = f(x).$$

We now want to prove the Newton-Leibniz formula
$$\int_a^b f(t)dt = F(b)-F(a).$$

Is it enough to simply say
$F(b)-F(a) =\int_a^b f(t)dt - \int_a^af(t)dt$, where the equality is by dfinition of $F$ and the last term is obvious zero.
Or is this proof circular?

Comment: If $F$ is defined like that then by definition $F(b) = \int_a^b f(t)dt$.

Comment: The reason I'm wondering is that $F$ is defined like that in the textbook, but then a somewhat more complicated proof is given for the Newton-Leibniz formula. And I'm just not sure why such a complication.

Comment: For the fundamental theorem it is assumed that $f$ is continuous whereas for the Newton-Leibniz it is not.

Comment: So if we want to prove the Newton-Leibniz formula in the case of continuous $f$, the proof is that trivial?

Comment: @JakeB. Yes, in that case it's a direct corollary. But the formula also holds when $f$ is integrable. Also, it seems like you're confusing something. In the Newton-Leibniz formula, you're given any antiderivative $F$, not necessarily defined as in the FTC.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your fundamental theorem calculus is

"If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $\displaystyle F(x):= \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$ with $F'(x)=f(x).$"

And your Newton-Leibniz formula is

"Let $f$ be integrable on $[a, b]$. If there exists a function $G$ on $[a,b]$ with $G'(x)=f(x)$ then $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(t) \, dt = G(b) - G(a)$."

Note that the function $f$ in the second statement need not to be continuous! So $G$ need not to be equal to $F$ in the first statement! However, as we see below, they won't be "too different" from each other if we make an additional assumption that $f$ to be continuous.

Now let's prove the second statement with our additional assumption by using the first statement:

Let say $G$ be a function such that $G'(x) = f(x)$ on $[a, b]$. We also know from the first statement that $F'(x)=f(x)$ on $[a, b]$. Thus, $G'(x)=F'(x)$ on $[a, b]$. By the mean value theorem there is a constant $C$ such that $G(x) = F(x) + C$ on $[a, b]$. Hence,

$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(t) \, dt = F(b) = F(b) - 0 = F(b) - F(a) = [F(b) + C] - [F(a) +C] = G(b) - G(a)$.